# How to link a profile to a newly created user using Django

Tags: python, django, django-signals, django-users

Just finished a website using Django and i got stuck after creating a user or superuser.

For some reason the same code i used before does not work anymore, and now whenever i create a new user it is saved (because i cant create another one with the same name) but not a profile for it.

So now, after the registration form, the user should be redirected to the profile page which brings back an error. If i try to restart the server and login again, same error appears.

Here is my signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

and models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)


TypeError at /register/
save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'
```

Comment: post view of `register`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the `save` method to match its [**`original function signature`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Signature/Function). Basically you need to pass arguments and keyword arguments through super function to make it work:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # rest of the code

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

Comment: I can`t believe i couldn`t figure that out! It worked perfectly, thank you!